# Creating a time series from CSV file where the timestamp has dmy hms format with a seasonaility and end time

Tags: r, time-series

```
Timestamp,XCV,VBN
30-03-2016 20:00,207,496
30-03-2016 20:06,213,500
30-03-2016 20:12,216,502
30-03-2016 20:18,223,503
30-03-2016 20:24,227,503
30-03-2016 20:30,226,503
30-03-2016 20:36,228,505
30-03-2016 20:42,233,507
30-03-2016 20:48,242,507
30-03-2016 20:54,257,509
30-03-2016 21:00,265,509
```

I tried using

```
df <- data.frame(interval = seq(
           from=as.POSIXct("10-03-2016 00:00",format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"),
           to=as.POSIXct("30-03-2016 21:00",format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"),
           by="6 mins")

ts(mydata,start=c(2010,03),frequency=24*60/10)
```

but it does not seems to work. Can anybody help here?

Comment: not sure how do you use data frame in your ts() function. Your timestamp is all within one hour.

Answer (score 1):

From [Freq values for minutes in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120806/frequency-value-for-seconds-minutes-intervals-data-in-r), you can specify the frequency using `60 / 6` as follows:

```
ts(df[-1], frequency=10)
```

Or you can use the `xts` library to read in your data and continue your analysis in the xts format.

```
library(xts)
xtsFmt <- xts(df[-1], as.POSIXct(df[[1]],format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))
as.ts(xtsFmt)
```

data:

```
df <- read.csv(text="Timestamp,XCV,VBN
30-03-2016 20:00,207,496
30-03-2016 20:06,213,500
30-03-2016 20:12,216,502
30-03-2016 20:18,223,503
30-03-2016 20:24,227,503
30-03-2016 20:30,226,503
30-03-2016 20:36,228,505
30-03-2016 20:42,233,507
30-03-2016 20:48,242,507
30-03-2016 20:54,257,509
30-03-2016 21:00,265,509
")
```

Comment: It solved one section for my problem, thanks for that.

The other section was :
df[-1] drops the data time stamp....
I should have asked the correct question.

I want to create a time series with start 10th Dec 2016 00:00 & end date 30th Dec 2016 21:06 and with frequency as the data has a pattern for every hour (data recorded in 6 minutes interval).

I was thinking to use SARIMA for forecasting,

Comment: use the `xts` class?